# Why is there no multiple or block comment in Ada?

Tags: comments, ada

Why is there no multiple or block comment in Ada programming like the C/C++ `/* */`?

Comment: I don't think C++ programmers actually use this kind of comment much any more.  Java programmers generally only use it for comments with a special format recognized by a documentation generator.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [Ada 83 Rationale Section 2.1](http://archive.adaic.com/standards/83rat/html/ratl-02-01.html#2.1) says

> No form of embedded comments (within a line of text) is provided, as their utility is insufficient to justify the extra complexity. Single comments that are larger than one line are not provided. Such comments would require a closing comment delimiter and this would again raise the dangers associated with the (unintentional) omission of the closing delimiter: entire sections of a program could be ignored by the compiler without the programmer realizing it, so that the program would not mean what he thinks. Long comments can be written as a succession of single line comments, thus combining elegance with safety.

Of course modern IDEs will colourise comments, but you might not notice, and the compiler certainly won’t.

Comment: Modern IDEs will also put line-comment indicators (`--` in Ada, `//` in many other languages) on blocks of multiple lines for you, lessening the need for the `/*...*/`-like syntax.

Comment: Multiple comments block is more used for debugging and hiding sections of code then actual comments when coding prototypes. Users may not be aware of or not having a IDE with comment colonizing tool thus making a multiple comments block useful for that type of situations.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use:

if(False) then

...
... Code goes here 
...

end if;

Comment: Alsmot sure it will trigger a compiler warning for unreacheable code (warnings in most critical software development process are treated as error)

Comment: This only allows you to comment out valid chunks of code, in addition to the comment mentioning this giving a compiler warning